# Are Exceptions for displaying to the user or just for developers?

Tags: php, exception

I  just recently read an article on http://phpmaster.com/exceptional-exceptions/ and he said this about exceptions:

> your calling code should never ever ever read the message. The only thing the message is good for is for developers.

On the W3Schools website they show an example where they output the exception message when it is caught so I am confused. I have learned a lot from http://www.phpmaster.com and trust what they say but W3Schools is always reliable too so which is the correct thing to do?

Is the exception message supposed to be outputted to the user or is it just something for developers? Maybe it isn't even that important and it can be used both ways without any harm?

Comment: _W3Schools is always reliable_.  Um, no.  Refer [W3Schools - An intervention](http://w3fools.com/).  Not familiar with PHP exceptions, but I'd agree that calling code shouldn't ever need  (or at least, _rarely_) to read an exception message (it would rather rely on the exception _type_).  But I'd disagree that exception messages are only ever for the developer; Well written exception messages can bubble out to the user so long as they're meaningful.

Comment: @Sepster Have you seen [this meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87678)?

Comment: @Basic No, I hadn't, but interesting.  To be clear, I wasn't suggesting W3C should _never_ be relied upon, I was just stating that it is NOT _always reliable_ as was the OP's assertion.

Comment: When you get a new hammer, every problem looks like a nail. **Please, stop abusing exceptions !!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the scenario but the biggest question is security. When a developer throws an exception, they usually try to include in the message some useful information about what exactly has gone wrong. They can't know if that information would be considered sensitive by you in the current context.

As an example, say you've got a website that has a login form. If the `Users` table in the database was missing and someone tried to log in, the exception thrown might be something like `Unable to find table users in database MyDb (db.mysite.com)`

If that message is displayed to a malicious user, they now know where your database is and what the db/table names are.

In this scenario, I tend to log the full exception with a unique Id and display the id to the user so they can follow-up with me later if required.

Conversely, if it's a desktop app then I tend to lean the other way - exception messages can help the end user (Eg an `Access Denied` is something the user may be able to resolve). Even then, you're not sure if the exception message will be useful (ala `Reference not set to an instance of an object`) so I tend to wrap any exception inside a more useful one (eg `Unable to connect to database`) and expose a list of all the Inner Exceptions. This means the user gets an understandable message but might also get more useful information if available and not a security risk

Comment: The message box with a details button to show the stackframe is a nice one on the desktop side. So you can have a description in english, with a hidden fallback for support and the devs.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson You're right, and seeing one always makes me feel less annoyed when a program crashes. I wish there were a standard framework dialogue for that but I've long since written my own.

Comment: me too. Email with log files as well. Anything to give you a clue what the "dumb" user did this time.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a clear answer. It depends on the information that the message gives.
If your messages don't supply any sensitive information you may print them to the client.

I like using the `$code` parameter in order to print the error to the client.
Something like that:

```
function clientError(Exception $e) {
    $error = 'Unknown error!';
    switch ($e->getCode()) {
        case 404:
            $error = 'Not found error!';
            break;
        case 403:
            $error = 'You cannot access this page!';
            break;
        ...
        ...
    }
    return "$error [error code: {$e->getCode()}]";
}
```

Save the error message in the error log and print the clientError to the client:

```
try {
    if (!$user->isMember()) {
        throw new Exception("Guest {$user->id} tried to access to newPost.php page", 403);
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $errorLog->newError($e);
    echo clientError($e);
}
```

This example should add a line in the error log with the message:
"Guest 123 tried to access to newPost.php page"
and print:
"You cannot access this page!"

Answer (score 1):

Almost right. You certainly don't want to present a hacker type with say a Stackframe. Presenting a user them isn't that useful either. Having said that, following this advice as it's presented falls into to to traps.

Sometimes the exception class you get is too generic and the only way to identify it is to test the text. OLE was classic for that. Run a sql statement you got OLEDB exception no matter what.
The other related one is when you do just try catch end and assume that the only exception that will be thrown is the one you thought might be, and then you get a user ringing up saying I'm getting "There is problem saving your document", which could be any one of a whole raft of problems.

No matter what else you do log the raw exception and the stackframe if you you get it. It's obvious, but way too many fall into this trap.

Don't go down the dumbing down the problem to the point of the message you present is totally useless route.

Even exceptions for devs have gone down that route Access Violation 0000000 at 0000000 was a good one, "Unknown ole error(5)" was brilliantly stupid, or the ever annoying msi one "error 1603".

Answer (score 0):

Re W3Schools: http://w3fools.com/

Exceptions are only for developers. They may contain information that would help an attacker hack your site, and they are not pretty. Catch the exception if you were expecting it and do something the user would expect e.g. display an error message they can understand. If you didn't expect an exception to happen, then you have a problem that you need to fix.

Uncaught exceptions are also known as 'bugs' ;)

Comment: Uncaught exceptions are known as bugs, depends on whether having caught them, they can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

mostly exceptions aren't helpful for end users for the lack of their experience in programming, you should handle your own exceptions and put a clear message for end users